# Informatica 9.1: If you pass sorted input to Aggregator then does it gives sorted output or it's random?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

In Informatica 9.1 unpartitioned mapping I am using a sorted aggregator and there is a joiner after that; can I make my joiner a sorted joiner?
The question here is that if you pass sorted input to aggregator than what are the chances of getting sorted output from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such scenarios are discussed in the *Advanced Transformation Guide*. Note the point highlighted in bold.

> When you add transformations between the sort origin and the Joiner
>   transformation, use the following guidelines to maintain sorted data:
>
> - Do not place any of the following transformations between the sort
>     origin and the Joiner transformation:
>
>   - Custom
>   - Unsorted Aggregator
>   - Normalizer
>   - Rank
>   - Union transformation
>   - XML Parser transformation
>   - XML Generator transformation
>   - Mapplet, if it contains one of the above transformations
> - **You can place a sorted Aggregator transformation between the sort
>     origin and the Joiner transformation if you use the following guidelines:**
>
>   - **Configure the Aggregator transformation for sorted input.**
>   - **Use the same ports for the group by columns in the Aggregator  transformation as the ports at the sort origin.**
>   - **The group by ports must be in the same order as the ports at the sort origin.**
> - When you join the result set of a Joiner transformation with
>     another pipeline, verify that the data output from the first Joiner transformation is sorted.
>
>   Tip: You can place the Joiner transformation directly after the sort
>     origin to maintain sorted data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the output is sorted and you can connect it to a joiner using sorted input. 
This is one instance where Informatica acts a little differently than Oracle. In a SQL if you pass sorted input and do a group by, the output may not necessarily be sorted.